# runValidators on mongoose update

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Below is the line in mongoose documentation(http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#update-validators):
**To turn on update validators, set the runValidators option for update() or findOneAndUpdate(). Be careful: update validators are off by default because they have several caveats.**

What are those caveats?
My requirement is to run validation before running an update. How to achieve that if there are caveats?

Comment: The caveats are explained directly below that line in the documentation.

Comment: You're probably better off with `pre save` [middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)